# Multi-byte strings and look-around weird bug

Tags: php, regex

Why following code behaves differently for different multi-bye strings?

```
echo preg_replace('@(?=\pL)@u', '*', 'م');  // prints: '*م'     ✓ 
echo preg_replace('@(?=\pL)@u', '*', 'ض');  // prints: '*ض'     ✓ 
echo preg_replace('@(?=\pL)@u', '*', 'غ');  // prints: '*�*�'   ✗ 
echo preg_replace('@(?=\pL)@u', '*', 'ص');  // prints: '*�*�'   ✗
```

See: http://3v4l.org/fvab1

Comment: It's not recognising `غ` as character. IMHO, it looks like a bug in the PCRE library but, being PHP, it's hard to say whether you need to enable something...

Comment: this working fine: echo preg_replace('/(.+)/', '*$1', 'غ');

Comment: Weirdly enough it seemed to work in older versions: http://3v4l.org/0Pq36

Comment: @deceze Thanks for info. +1 for link

Comment: String manipulation is very painful using PHP . I hope PHP 6 will be released in this century.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include modifier letters as well (`Lm`). See the following script iterating over the whole arabic unicode block:

```
<?php
function uchar_2($dec)
{
    $utf = chr(192 + (($dec - ($dec % 64)) / 64)); 
    $utf .= chr(128 + ($dec % 64)); 


    return $utf;
}

$issues = 0;
$count = 0;
for ($dec = 1536; $dec <= 1791; $dec++) {
    $char = uchar_2($dec);
    if (preg_replace('@^(?=\pLm)$@u', '*', $char) !== $char) {
        printf("Issue with %s (%s)\n", $dec, $char);
        $issues++;
    }
    $count++;
}

printf("Found %d issues in %d rows\n", $issues, $count);
```

With out `Lm`, this will fail for around half of the characters.

Comment: In your code even using `'@^(?=\pL)$@u'` returns no issue. But if you use '@(?=\pL)@u' it returns some issues. In the code using `\pLm` show desired output. But it must work with `\pL` as well.